# To qualify "ROS-Industrial" package

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just wondering what makes a package "ROS-Industrial" package?

For example [universal_robot](http://wiki.ros.org/universal_robot) as far as I examined doesn't depend on any of `industrial_*` packages unlike other ROS-I robot drivers (motoman, fanuc etc.) but its wiki page states `This stack is part of the ROS Industrial program.`

```
$ rospack depends1 ur_bringup 
tf2_ros
ur_description
ur_driver
$ rospack depends1 ur_description 
urdf
$ rospack depends1 ur_driver
rospy
actionlib
control_msgs
sensor_msgs
trajectory_msgs
ur_msgs
dynamic_reconfigure
$ rospack depends1 ur_msgs
message_runtime
std_msgs
```

Using [this commit](https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot/commit/4cfe91d8b0efdfdf1989055e21333ceef01f1899)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216621/to-qualify-%22ros-industrial%22-package/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2015-08-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, so here's my perspective (this is not necessarily the *official answer* though):

> Just wondering what makes a package "ROS-Industrial" package?

This is a hard question to answer, as there is no certification system in place yet. At the moment, saying that a package is *in the ROS-Industrial program* essentially means that:

- the package is hosted on the ROS-Industrial [github organisation](https://github.com/ros-industrial)
- is (normally) used in industrial contexts
- *may be* supported / maintained / contributed by the manufacturer (in case of drivers)
- is *always* maintained by the ROS-Industrial [organisation](http://ros-i.org) (either the consortium directly, or one of its members)
- has gone through a review process (this is not an official review or audit yet, but currently based on the many eyes principle)

For packages in the ROS-Industrial [Consortium organisation](https://github.com/ros-industrial-consortium) it also means that they are the result of one or more [Focused Technical Project](http://rosindustrial.org/ric/about-ftps/)(s) or Strategic Projects.

In general we strive to provide continuity for the many packages we support. This has been something that industry users value, and is one of the aspects with which ROS-Industrial tries to differentiate itself from 'normal ROS' (if there is such a thing).

> For example universal_robot as far as I examined doesn't depend on any of `industrial_*` packages unlike other ROS-I robot drivers (motoman, fanuc etc.)

This is not (and has never been) a requirement. Another example are the various packages in the [Robotiq](https://github.com/ros-industrial/robotiq) repository: none of those depends on `industrial_*` packages either, but they *are* part of ROS-Industrial.

As far as *software interfaces* go, one could say that adherence to the ROS-Industrial (motion) driver specification would make a package more 'industrial', but that does not immediately make that package *part of* ROS-Industrial.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) on 2015-09-01**:
+1...well stated.